# Convert xarray with cell dimension (+ lon/lat coordinates) into a grid based xarray (lon/lat dimensions)

Tags: python-xarray

I have an xarray Dataset ds1 (can also be a DataArray) that looks like this (code below):

```py
ds1
# <xarray.Dataset>
# Dimensions:    (cell: 6, time: 1, band: 12)
# Coordinates:
#     latitude   (cell) float32 51.25 51.75 52.25 52.75 53.25 53.75
#     longitude  (cell) float32 7.75 7.75 7.75 7.75 7.75 7.75
#   * cell       (cell) int64 27410 27411 27412 27413 27414 27415
#   * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 2022-12-31
#   * band       (band) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
# Data variables:
#     landuse    (cell, time, band) float64 0.2819 0.1255 0.5831 ... 0.7683 0.534
#     harvest    (cell, time) float64 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
```

Now this format is not in the shape of longitude, latitude matrix that can be written to NetCDF as a 2d map or where selections based on the latitude and longitude can performed on (nearest neighbor, etc.). So I want to convert it into a grid (lat-lon matrix) like this:

```py
ds2
# <xarray.Dataset>
# Dimensions:    (longitude: 720, latitude: 280, band: 12, time: 1)
# Coordinates:
#   * longitude  (longitude) float64 -179.8 -179.3 -178.8 ... 178.8 179.3 179.8
#   * latitude   (latitude) float64 -55.75 -55.25 -54.75 ... 82.75 83.25 83.75
#   * band       (band) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
#   * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 2022-12-31
# Data variables:
#     landuse    (longitude, latitude, band, time) float64 nan nan nan ... nan nan
#     harvest    (longitude, latitude, time) float64 nan nan nan ... nan nan nan
```

Problem is that I do not find a way to convert it properly.

Here is my example code to generate both and my previous attempt to convert it ...

```py
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

# My output data set --------------------------------------------------------- #

# Define coordinates
cell = np.arange(27410, 27416)
lat = np.array([51.25, 51.75, 52.25, 52.75, 53.25, 53.75], dtype=np.float32)
lon = np.full(6, 7.75, dtype=np.float32)
band = np.arange(12)
time = np.array(['2022-12-31'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')

# Create empty dataset
ds1 = xr.Dataset()
ds1 = ds1.assign_coords(latitude=('cell', lat),
                        longitude=('cell', lon),
                        cell=cell,
                        time=time,
                        band=band)
ds1 = ds1.set_coords(['latitude', 'longitude'])

# Create empty data variables
landuse = xr.DataArray(
    np.full((6, 1, 12), np.nan),
    dims=['cell', 'time', 'band']
)
harvest = xr.DataArray(np.full((6, 1), np.nan), dims=['cell', 'time'])

# Assign data variables to dataset
ds1['landuse'] = landuse
ds1['harvest'] = harvest

# Assign values to the data variables
ds1['landuse'][:, :, :] = np.random.rand(6, 1, 12)
ds1['harvest'][:, :] = np.random.randint(2, size=(6, 1))


# Dataset with latitude and longitude matrix --------------------------------- #

# Define dimensions and coordinates
lon = np.linspace(-179.8, 179.8, 720)
lat = np.linspace(-55.75, 83.75, 280)

# Create empty dataset
ds2 = xr.Dataset()

ds2 = ds2.assign_coords(longitude=lon,
                        latitude=lat,
                        band=band,
                        time=time)

landuse = xr.DataArray(np.full((720, 280, 12, 1), np.nan),
                       dims=['longitude', 'latitude', 'band', 'time'])

harvest = xr.DataArray(np.full((720, 280, 1), np.nan),
                       dims=['longitude', 'latitude', 'time'])

ds2['landuse'] = landuse
ds2['harvest'] = harvest
```

My previous attempt to convert it ...

```py
ds3 = ds2.where(
    (ds1.longitude == ds2.longitude) & (ds1.latitude == ds2.longitude),
    ds1
)
```

The result looks like this:

```py
d3
# <xarray.Dataset>
# Dimensions:    (longitude: 720, latitude: 280, band: 12, time: 1, cell: 6)
# Coordinates:
#   * longitude  (longitude) float64 -179.8 -179.3 -178.8 ... 178.8 179.3 179.8
#   * latitude   (latitude) float64 -55.75 -55.25 -54.75 ... 82.75 83.25 83.75
#   * band       (band) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
#   * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 2022-12-31
#   * cell       (cell) int64 27410 27411 27412 27413 27414 27415
# Data variables:
#     landuse    (longitude, latitude, band, time, cell) float64 0.9636 ... 0.3648
#     harvest    (longitude, latitude, time, cell) float64 1.0 1.0 0.0 ... 0.0 0.0
```

but should ideally look like this (without cell dimension):

```py
# <xarray.Dataset>
# Dimensions:    (longitude: 720, latitude: 280, band: 12, time: 1)
# Coordinates:
#   * longitude  (longitude) float64 -179.8 -179.3 -178.8 ... 178.8 179.3 179.8
#   * latitude   (latitude) float64 -55.75 -55.25 -54.75 ... 82.75 83.25 83.75
#   * band       (band) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
#   * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 2022-12-31
# Data variables:
#     landuse    (longitude, latitude, band, time, cell) float64 0.9636 ... 0.3648
#     harvest    (longitude, latitude, time, cell) float64 1.0 1.0 0.0 ... 0.0 0.0
```

I would be interested in a proper solution here that also is shorter, ideally only cell dimension should be switched with longitude, latitude (with possibly extending longitudes and latitudes).

Comment: A problem is that what you have right now as `ds1` is 1 dimensional data, since you only have one coordinate `cell`. So you can only have `len(cell)` values in your dataset. I don't know if this is what you intended